# I'm trying to install this package but i can't! Xunit.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

Please i want Install Unit Test
'Xunit.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting 1.0.0-beta-1011'. You are attempting to install this package in a project that has '. NETFramework, Version = v4. 5 1' as a destination, but the package does not contain assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, please contact the author of the package. 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dll you are trying to add, `Xunit.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`, doesn't match the target framework of your project.

Specifically, the DLL you are trying to add is a beta version needing .NET framework 4.6, and you project is currently .NET 4.5.1.

You could either change the target framework of your project, or look for a matching dll.

To see/change, target framework of your project:

1. Right click project's name
2. Click on "Properties"
3. There you will see "Target framework" dropdown (under Application tab, that should be open by default)

[image]

See: https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-desktop.html#add-xunit-ref

As a side note, if you are experiencing the following error, after changing your target framework to 4.6:
`Install-Package : 'NETStandard.Library' already has a dependency defined...`, try updating your nuget installation.

Comment: not i changed to .net framework 4.6 and it doens't work

Comment: Please post the error you are getting now, it must of changed

Comment: It's the same error and just changed the version...

Comment: Okay i want to do Basic Unit Test.... That's all but i can't install the package.

Comment: try not working with the beta version, see the link at the bottom of my anwer

Comment: look for xunit in nuget manager, or run Install-Package xunit -Version 2.1.0

Comment: well i installed everthing less xunit.runner.console... i can't still do the Assert. Say problems about version

Comment: Please post the error

Comment: Mate not problem i fixed it! thank you!